# Android studio action bar text

Tags: android, xml

How do i write text in my android studio action bar ? I want to write a text two separate text on my action bar like whatsapp has . I see on it the code I was given but it doesn't show me how to do it .

action bar :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: use ToolBar with custom layout instead of action bar.

Comment: How do I use that one ?

Answer (score 0):

Reference [see google docs](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html).

use Theme **Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar** ...

In your layout include--

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Your activity must look like--

```
    public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    }
}
```